# Does my SSD not mount because it’s full?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, disk-space

I’m having issues booting. And in order to boot I need to mount this but it won’t work no matter what I try the only thing I’m thinking is that it’s because it is full.

Does this have anything to do with it not being able to mount and what can I do about it? I try erasing and it journals and guids fine, but around the part where it is mounting during erase process the computer freezes.
How do I free up space on this?

[image]
[image]

EDIT: when I try mounting in the other recovery mode that prompts Catalina instead of capitan it gives me this error.

When I try to erase and format with APFS I get a crash prompted with this.
[image]

[image]